# Get list of users with viewer right to powerBI report using powershell

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am trying to create script in which I want to get list of users with who i have shared my powerBI reports or users with view rights. I want to get this information using powershell. I can get list of users with access to group/workspace through API call. But i am not able to find any parameter or method in powershell by which I get PowerBI reports users.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [Microsoft Power BI Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps). From there you can get your workspace using [Get-PowerBIWorkspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.workspaces/get-powerbiworkspace?view=powerbi-ps) cmdlet and find the list of users of the workspace in the property `Users`:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

Clear-Host

$username = "user@example.com"
$password = "psssword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential | Out-Null

$workspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name "My awesome workspace" -Scope Organization

foreach($user in $workspace.Users) {
    Write-Host "$($user.Identifier), $($user.AccessRight), $($user.PrincipalType)"
}

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

Where `AccessRight` will tell you is it `Admin`, `Member`, `Contributor` or `Viewer`.

Comment: Thanks! Andrey, But i think this will give me users with access to workspace, How can i get details of users with viewer rights to report- "ABC"

Comment: I don't think there is an API that can return this information (yet).

Comment: Yeah, I looked every where but could not find any user property for reports, that is why i came here to check if i was missing something, but if it is not possible then i think it is a big miss in API.